# How to shorten multiple isset functions in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

Look at my script:

```
if((isset($_POST['unma']) && isset($_POST['livi'])) && (isset($_POST['cont']) && 

    isset($_POST['phone']))){
        if(
            (
                (
                    (
                        (isset($_POST['fnma']) && isset($_POST['lnma']))
                        &&
                        (isset($_POST['occ']) && isset($_POST['hom']))
                    )
                    &&
                    (
                        (isset($_POST['town']) && isset($_POST['dist']))
                        &&
                        (isset($_POST['dispmb']) && isset($_POST['fbc']))
                    )
                )
                &&
                (
                    (
                        (isset($_POST['gp']) && isset($_POST['twt']))
                        &&
                        (isset($_POST['ins']) && isset($_POST['flc']))
                    )
                    &&
                    (
                        (isset($_POST['ile']) && isset($_POST['cam']))
                        &&
                        (isset($_POST['cam_co']) && isset($_POST['prof_phr']))
                    )
                )
            )
            &&
            isset($_POST['awards'])
        ){
                // Codes here
        }
```

How can I short this `isset` functions. I found an solution with `foreach` but they are not checking the post `isset`, rather they are checking if the posted values are not empty

Comment: sidenote: `isset($var, $var2, $var3)` is also valid

Comment: is that all post field are text box or other fields

Comment: Pass an array of your $_POST vars into a function which executes an isset "foreach" entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
if (isset($_POST['a'], $_POST['b'], $_POST['c'], ...))
```

and so on. If any of the variables is not set then you will get `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$expectedKeys = ['fnma', 'lnma', ...];
if (!array_diff_key(array_flip($expectedKeys), $_POST)) {
    // all keys are set
}
```

Comment: @JakeGould what is more wanted than checking the keys?

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not sure if `isset()` checks for value. It checks for presentation of the variable in the current memory load.

Comment: @JakeGould There will be no difference here. `isset` is `true` is the key exists and is not `null`. Since POSTed values can never be `null`, the only thing it really does is to check for the existence of keys. And this code here does the same.

Comment: @JakeGould I wonder how you could manage to send null post fields. And the leak here is that there are a lot of ways to have empty variable value without it being NULL constant. Isset will not catch them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
 // add all names of the values that needs to be set in the `$_POST` array
 $values = array('fnma', 'lnma');

 function checkSet($array) {
   foreach($array as $value) {
     if(!isset($_POST[$value])) return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
 if(checkSet($values)) {
   // your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

put required fields in a array and check for it using loop,it is easy and easy to add required fields.

```
$req_values = array('fnma','lnma','occ','hom','town','dist','dispmb','fbc','gp','twt','ins','flc','ile','cam','cam_co','prof_phr');


foreach($req_values as $key) {
  if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
           echo $key .'is required';
           exit;
      }
}
```

Comment: Note that `empty` is not the same as `!isset`.

Comment: i prefer empty instead of `isset()`, because if a variable is like this `$a='';` then `isset()` will be true but not `empty()`

Comment: That's why I'm saying it's not the same thing. It depends on what you want to test for.

Comment: yes,but here he is testing whether it is empty or not? so in my opinion empty() will give the best result

Comment: No, he's testing whether the array keys *are set* or not, nobody mentioned an emptiness test... :)

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that [`isset`](https://www.php.net/issetarray_values) can take multiple values, you could do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['unma'], $_POST['livi'], $_POST['cont'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['fnma'], $_POST['lnma'], $_POST['occ'], $_POST['hom'], $_POST['town'], $_POST['dist'], $_POST['dispmb'], $_POST['fbc'], $_POST['gp'], $_POST['tat'], $_POST['ins'], $_POST['flc'], $_POST['ile'], $_POST['cam'], $_POST['cam_co'], $_POST['prof_phr'], $_POST['awards'])) {
    // Codes here
}
```

But that seems nightmarish. I would make the `$_POST` keys an array & then do the following:

```
// Set an array of post values.
$post_values = array('unma','livi','cont','phone','fnma','lnma','occ','hom','town','dist','dispmb','fbc','gp','tat','ins','flc','ile','cam','cam_co','prof_phr','awards');

// Set '$post_valid' to an array.
$post_valid = array();

// Roll through the post values.
foreach ($post_values AS $post_key => $post_value) {
  // If the value is  set, set '$post_valid' to TRUE or else set it to FALSE.
  // $post_valid = isset($_POST[$post_key]) ? TRUE : FALSE; // Not really needed. Simple `isset` should work.
  $post_valid[$post_key] = !empty($_POST[$post_key]);
}

// Now if '$post_valid' values are all true, do something.
$post_valid_values = array_values($post_valid);
if (!empty($post_valid_values) && (count($post_valid_values) == count($post_values))){
  // Codes here
}
```

Comment: The only thing needed to pass this test is that the *last* key isset. It does not accumulate all tests in `$post_valid`. Also, `isset($_POST[$post_key]) ? TRUE : FALSE` is the same as `isset($_POST[$post_key])`.

Comment: I mean, all keys could be unset with only `awards` being set, and this would still return `true` for `$post_valid`. That's certainly broken, isn't it?

Comment: `!empty(array_values)` will produce an error in all but the very latest PHP version. You also don't need to check `isset && !empty`, just `!empty` will do the same thing.